# MySQL PHP pdo insert value is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table with
id - integer AUTO INCREMENT
productid varchar
photo varchar
I use pdo for mysql connection
the code below is giving my an error please any help

```
$photo = $_POST['photo'];
$product = $_SESSION['prd'];
$todo = $dblink->query("INSERT INTO productphotos VALUES (NULL, '".$product."', '".$photo."'") or die ("Erorr");
```

Best Reagrds
Thank You

Comment: ("INSERT INTO productphotos VALUES (NULL, '".$product."', '".$photo."')") missing close parenthesis?

Comment: no problem. Just try to read your query carefully, you might be facing that again if you have huge queries. :)

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble of concatenating values into your SQL and use a prepared statement

```
$stmt = $dblink->prepare('INSERT INTO productphotos VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute([$product, $photo]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['photo'], $_SESSION['prd'])){
//data
$photo = $_POST['photo'];
$product = $_SESSION['prd'];

$query = "INSERT INTO productphotos VALUES (NULL, :product, :photo)"
$stmt = $dblink->prepare($query);;
$stmt->bindValue(':product', $product, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindValue(':photo', $photo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute(); 
}
```

And you should really make sure you set your connection to throw errors

```
$dblink->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```